# How to properly use duplicate functions in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my code the following functions are repeated: (Because I'm using several codes to mix different functions to create my installer).

```
CurInstallProgressChanged

CancelButtonClick

InitializeWizard

CurPageChanged
```

Is it okay to rename these functions to `CancelButtonClick1` and `2` (for example), etc, so as not to have errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is obsolete as of Inno Setup 6. For an up-to-date answer, see [Merging event function (InitializeWizard) implementations from different sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40512631/850848)*.

---

The `CurInstallProgressChanged` and the `CancelButtonClick1` have to have that name. You cannot name them `CurInstallProgressChanged1` and the `CancelButtonClick1` and expect them to be magically called.

You call the `InitializeWizard1` and the `InitializeWizard2` from the `InitializeWizard`. But you do not call the `CurInstallProgressChanged1` or the `CancelButtonClick1` anywhere.

If you have only one implementation of an event function, there's no need to append a number to its name. Keep the `CurInstallProgressChanged` and the `CancelButtonClick`.

---

Then, you have two implementations of the `CurPageChanged` (the `CurPageChanged1` and the `CurPageChanged2`), but you do not have the main implementation `CurPageChanged`.

---

As the [answer, I've already pointed you to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40512631/850848#40512997) says:

> When you are reusing various feature implementations from different sources, those **commonly implement the same Inno Setup event functions** (like the `InitializeWizard`).
>
> You have to merge these event functions as there can be just one function implementation.
>
> You can do that by appending unique suffix to the different implementation and than **calling them from a main implementation**.