# How to unzip multiple files with InnoTools post install?

Tags: inno-setup, unzip

The script sample I have came from http://www.saidsimple.com/daniel/blog/117966/ and it’s only set for one zip. I want to be able to unzip any zips in a particular location. I guess one approach might be a wildcard *.zip when the zip name might vary depending on earlier installer selections.

No unzipping occurs. I’ve missed defining something or procedure is not setup properly. In my use the zips are text files the intended program reads for functions.

```
[Setup] …
SolidCompression=true
Compression=lzma
CreateAppDir=false
DirExistsWarning=false
ShowLanguageDialog=false
CreateUninstallRegKey=no
#include <idp.iss>

[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\text.net";  DestDir: "{userappdata}\ccc"; Flags: external; Components: abc
Source: "{tmp}\HLNJ.zip";  DestDir: "{userappdata}\ccc"; Flags: external deleteafterinstall; Components: hlnj
Source: "{tmp}\HNJ.zip"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\ccc"; Flags: external deleteafterinstall; Components: hnj

[Code]
const
  SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX = 4;
  SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL = 16;
procedure InitializeWizard; ...
begin ...
end;
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep); ...
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin ...
end;
end;

procedure unzip(ZipFile, TargetFldr: PAnsiChar);
var
 shellobj: variant;
 ZipFileV, TargetFldrV: variant;
 SrcFldr, DestFldr: variant;
 shellfldritems: variant;
begin
 if FileExists('{userappdata}\ccc\HLNJ.zip') then begin
 ForceDirectories('{userappdata}\ccc’);
 shellobj := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
 ZipFileV := string(ZipFile);
 TargetFldrV := string(TargetFldr);
 SrcFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(ZipFileV);
 DestFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(TargetFldrV);
 shellfldritems := SrcFldr.Items;
 DestFldr.CopyHere(shellfldritems, SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX or SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL); 
 end;
end;

procedure ExtractSomething(src, target : AnsiString);
begin
 unzip(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));

end;
```

I would expect one of the zips to be unzipped. But nothing, even in inno log; nothing happens in this section of code. At least deletion of zip works.

EDIT: I’m revisiting an issue I did not solve last year. The problem is getting the Unzip to work. Zip downloads to location but is deleted without unzipping first.
EDIT 2: Might not be the best but appears to work. I’ve changed my recent code to a working version for Inno 5 (edited the filenames, removed setup.)

```
; #pragma include __INCLUDE__ + ";" + ReadReg(HKLM, "Software\Mitrich Software\Inno Download Plugin", "InstallDir")
#pragma include __INCLUDE__ + ";" + "c:\lib\InnoDownloadPlugin"

[Setup]
#include <idp.iss>

[Types]
Name: custom;  Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: conn;  Description: “CC File”;  Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: hlnj;  Description: “H L (Recommended)”; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive

[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\text.net";  DestDir: "{userappdata}\ccc”; Flags: external; Components: conn
Source: "{tmp}\HLNJ.zip”;  DestDir: "{userappdata}\ccc”; Flags: external deleteafterinstall; Components: hlnj conn

[Code]
const
  SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX = 4;
  SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL = 16;
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    idpAddFileComp('http://ccc.sourceforge.net/text.net',  ExpandConstant('{tmp}\text.net'),  'conn');
    idpAddFileComp('http://ccc.sourceforge.net/SecurityUpdates/HLNJ.zip',  ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HLNJ.zip'), 'hlnj');

    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged1(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin
    FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\text.net'), ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\ccc\text.net'), false);
    FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HLNJ.zip'), ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\ccc\HLNJ.zip'), false);
end;
end;

procedure unzip(ZipFile, TargetFldr: variant);
var
 shellobj: variant;
 SrcFldr, DestFldr: variant;
 shellfldritems: variant;
begin
 if FileExists(ZipFile) then begin
   if not DirExists(TargetFldr) then 
      if not ForceDirectories(TargetFldr) then begin
        MsgBox('Can not create folder '+TargetFldr+' !!', mbError, MB_OK);
        Exit;
      end;   

   shellobj := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
   SrcFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(ZipFile);
   DestFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(TargetFldr);
   shellfldritems := SrcFldr.Items;
   DestFldr.CopyHere(shellfldritems, SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX or SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL);

if FileExists(TargetFldr+'\HLNJ.zip') then MsgBox('HLNJ.zip'+ZipFile+
 ' extracted to '+TargetFldr, mbInformation, MB_OK);
 end else MsgBox('HLNJ.zip  does not exist', mbError, MB_OK);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin
     unzip(ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\ccc\HLNJ.zip'),ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\ccc'));
  end;
  end;
```

Comment: Still the same: *"You never call `ExtractSomething` – You need to call it from `CurStepChanged`"* as the answer by @moskito-x shows.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Changing the last step to CurStepChanged as in the example provided clashes with the CurStepChanged used during the file download portion. I'm struggling to figure out how to change the procedure name of one or the other, or solve this another way.

Comment: See [Merging event function (InitializeWizard) implementations from different sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40512631/850848).

Comment: I’ve changed my recent code to a working version for Inno 5 (edited the filenames, removed setup.) Important to note: the Mitrich download plug-in used here is incompatible with Inno 6. Inno 6 apparently finally has its own download abilities but I’m unable to find refs online & within app how to use it. Inno 5 on my small footprint Win XP for now is fine. Huge thanks to both moskito-x and Martin Prikryl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not even extract one .zip file.**
So step by step first one and then ...

The code is not complete.
So one can only guess what is missing or wrong.

To test the proper functioning of the `unzip` procedure you should use a simple standard inno-setup program.

If this works you can add extra features and then find the error easier.

Also the used constants "src" and "target" are not visible.
How are they constructed?

```
unzip(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));
```

The use of different types of data should be avoided.

**AnsiString vs PAnsiChar**

```
procedure unzip(ZipFile, TargetFldr: PAnsiChar);
....
end;

procedure ExtractSomething(src, target : AnsiString);
begin
  unzip(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));
end;
```

The use of {tmp} will, I suspect, made by the #include `idp.iss` download.
This code also not exists.

We will simulate this and use a known zip file from a known directory. So we do not need the download of the files.

**Information also does not harm but makes it easier to find fault.**
I used some MsgBox() for that.

**A simple procedure is for the beginning following.**

- Copy the HLNJ.zip file to C:\HLNJ.zip
  and look for a file or folder name part of the `HLNJ.zip`
  so we can test the extraction.
- I use here a file named `atext.txt` wich is part of my `HLNJ.zip`

`CreateOleObject` needs variants so use them instead.

```
 [Files]
 ; Simulate the download of HLNJ.zip is ok
 ; On the development PC .. on the client PC.
 Source: "C:\HLNJ.zip"; DestDir: "{tmp}";

 ; Now "HLNJ.zip" is in the {tmp} folder so we can use it.
 Source: "{tmp}\HLNJ.zip";  DestDir: "{userappdata}\ccc"; Flags: external deleteafterinstall

[Code]
const
  SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX = 4;
  SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL = 16;

....

procedure unzip(ZipFile, TargetFldr: variant);// <--- variant instead of PAnsiChar 
var
 shellobj: variant;
 SrcFldr, DestFldr: variant;
 shellfldritems: variant;
begin
 if FileExists(ZipFile) then begin
   if not DirExists(TargetFldr) then 
      if not ForceDirectories(TargetFldr) then begin
        MsgBox('Can not create folder '+TargetFldr+' !!', mbError, MB_OK);
        Exit;
      end;    

   shellobj := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
   SrcFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(ZipFile);
   DestFldr := shellobj.NameSpace(TargetFldr);
   shellfldritems := SrcFldr.Items;
   DestFldr.CopyHere(shellfldritems, SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX or SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL);

   if FileExists(TargetFldr+'\atext.txt') then MsgBox('ZipFile '+ZipFile+
     ' extracted to '+TargetFldr, mbInformation, MB_OK);

 end else MsgBox('ZipFile '+ZipFile+' does not exist', mbError, MB_OK);
end;


procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin
     unzip(ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\ccc\HLNJ.zip'),ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\ccc\extracted'));
  end;
end;
```

[image]